# Force download is slow in XMLHTTPRequest but not in Form Handler

Tags: javascript, php

I have used XMLHttpRequest to a php script where the script will response with a force download using following headers, example.php

```
 <?php
 if(file_exist($requestedFile))
 {
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header("Content-type: application/zip");           
 header("Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename=\"" . basename($requestedFile) . "\"" );
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");  
 header("Pragma:  public");
 header("Cache-Control:  no cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
 header("Content-Length:  " . filesize($requestedFile));
 ob_end_flush();
 readfile($requestedFile);
 exit();
 }
?>
```

and then, in my Javascript, i have made a blob of the response and save it

```
<script>         
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
     function sendData() {
     var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
     var FD = new FormData(form);
     XHR.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
     if(XHR.status == 200)
    {
    var blob = new Blob([XHR.response], {type: 'application/zip'}); 
    var fileName = XHR.getResponseHeader("Content- 
    Disposition").match(/\sfilename="([^"]+)"(\s|$)/)[1];  
    saveBlob(blob, fileName);   
    }
    XHR.open("POST", "/plugins/download.php");
    XHR.responseType = "blob";
    XHR.send(FD);
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");    
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    sendData();});

function saveBlob(blob, fileName) {    
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);  
    a.download = fileName;    
    a.click(); 
}
</script>
```

When force download a 600~MB zip, the 'Download' took so long time to start(20 min)(in line 37. if(xhr.status == 200)). It took ~1 min for a 7~MB zip.(which seems normal) 
BUT, if i replace above the XMLHTTPRequest approach with the Form Handler

```
<Form action="example.php", method="POST">
```

Then, the download begin immediately despite of the file size.

Anyone know why such difference happened between this two approach?

My development Enviroment:
PHP 5.3.29
Apache 2.2.31
Browser: Chrome

Comment: _“Anyone know why such difference happened between this two approach?”_ - because with your first approach, you are forcing the browser to handle at least 600 MB worth of data in memory, to create the BLOB …?

Comment: Thans for the reply, as i debug, the wait time does not happened at 'Creating the BLOB' at 'var blob = new Blob([XHR.response], {type: 'application/zip'});' 
I have been waited for 20 minit before it hit the line
if(XHR.status == 200). But if i use the form POST action approach instead of XMLHTTPRequest web api, then the download is instant.